# getTabHost() - Cannot resolve method

Tags: java, android

I tried create a tab bar using [this tutorial](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-tab-bar-example-1/). But in this line:

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
```

I received the message:

> Cannot resolve the method "getTabHost()"

This is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feeds);

    //add tab bar
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, FeedsFriendsActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("First").setIndicator("First")
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, FeedsBeersActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second").setIndicator("Second")
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, FeedsNotificationActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third").setIndicator("Third")
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please edit and show the entire class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TabHost is deprecated, It is recommended to use the new Material design tab layout as shown in this tutorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/